# Why is my Pandas df output different to my Excel input?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to create a dataset using 2 worksheets from multiple different workbooks (ultimately i will use 72 worksheets).

to simplify my issue i will use the most simple worksheet - i want my code to produce a table that shows only 4 rows per my worksheet. right now the output for df2 doesn't correspond with what is in the worksheet (17 rows??) and i have no idea why? is anyone able to enlighten me?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\me\workbook', 'TB-Income Statement', usecols = "F:H")
df2.insert(0, "Date", "Dec-21")
df2.insert(0, "Source", "I/S")
df2.insert(0, "Fund", "SCML")
df2.rename(columns ={'GL Account Number':'GL A/C No.',
                     'GL Account Name':'GL A/C Name',
                     'PTD':'Amount ($)'}, inplace = True)

df2
```

Here is the data i want to show in `df2`:

[image]

But this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have mentioned the sheet name properly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ editing as i misread - i believe so - i have copied from the excel worksheet tab and i get 'TB-Income Statement'. what is bizarre is some of these rows don't exist anywhere in this workbook.

Comment: Have you checked the data types for the columns, both in python and excel?

Comment: Please share the entire code.. I hope you have done some data processing.

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ this is my complete code. i am just creating multiple dfs from different worksheets in different workbooks. i have not done any data processing - what would you suggest in this regard?

Comment: @fam-woodpecker these are the data types in python:
Fund            object
Source          object
Date            object
GL A/C No.     float64
GL A/C Name     object
Amount ($)     float64
dtype: object

whereas in excel they are all 'General' apart from column H which is 'Custom'

Comment: Have you filtered records in Excel Sheet? Please check on that

Comment: @omclinto the custom column in excel, what is it customised to?

Comment: @fam-woodpecker i don't actually know as all of the workbooks have been created by someone else. i like your line of questioning though, it seems the data isn't actually as clean as i presumed it was and probably explains the values in the last column.

Comment: Did you try to output df2 before manipulating the data (just to verify that you get the right data)?

Comment: hi all - i think you've helped me solve this (alongside some extra digging on stackexchange) - 1 further q from my side - how can i get the value '2.141759e+09' to show as '2,141,758,632.20' ?